# Flickering view like facebook feed with dynamic image size and with using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I want to make facebook like news feed. I'm using Glide.
I have ImageView width set to match_parent and height to wrap_content.
It kinda works, but I have many flickering and sometimes wrong image size while scrolling up and down. Any idea how to make this work nice?